# How to get share counts using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I can get the share count of an URL using PHP SDK and using the deprecated rest API, but didn't find a way to get the share counts of an URL using graph API.

Is there any way to find out?

Comment: Get the solution for you in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137414/how-to-fetch-facebook-likes-share-comments-count-from-an-article

Comment: Please check answer at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url/35062056#35062056

Comment: Post August 8th, 2016 (non-deprecated) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39379251/4607317

Answer (score 271):

Here's a list of API links to get your stats:

> Facebook:
>   https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%%URL%%&format=json
>   Reddit:http://buttons.reddit.com/button_info.json?url=%%URL%%
>   LinkedIn: http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=%%URL%%&format=json 
> Digg:
>   http://widgets.digg.com/buttons/count?url=%%URL%% 
> Delicious:
>   http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=%%URL%%
>   StumbleUpon:
>   http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=%%URL%%
>   Pinterest:
>   http://widgets.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?source=6&url=%%URL%%

Edit:
Removed the Twitter endpoint, since that one has been deprecated.

Edit:
Facebook REST API is deprecated

Comment: The linkedin one does not work (gives 403 access denied)

Comment: I have fixed the url for linkedin.

Comment: The callback for the twitter URL is a bit of a red herring - it isn't necessary and if you're trying to use json_decode (PHP) to process the data it will fail if its wrapped in a callback.

Comment: And not very convenient link to Vkontakte share counter - https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=%%URL%%

Comment: The count for Google+ can be found (in a slightly more complicated way!) as given in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385591/1312282

Comment: How much is the API call limit for each request?

Comment: @StErMi there *usually* aren't limits for these URLs as they don't require any auth (though the results may be cached).  But not all the URLs are "officially" supported, which is important to bear in mind.

Comment: Hi there ! Thanks for this list. I can't find the documentation for the  https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats API endpoint. It indeed works but I would like to ensure it's not part of a API version that will be decommissioned soon. Also it is strange that this is available without authentication... Do you see anything about this in the facebook documentation ? It is not part of the graph API...

Comment: Also,can we filter the number of counts for certain period.Like 1 week,1 month,...i need to count for 1 month only,any idea?

Comment: Seems like twitter is no longer available

Comment: Facebook link is not working anymore. Use http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com

Comment: @MarkOverride an even more optimized version (less bandwidth) is http://graph.facebook.com/?fields=share&id=http://www.google.com .
The problem is that these new endpoints are severely rate-limited and it's very hard to use them in production without encountering said limits. If somebody has a different way to do it please let us know.

Comment: @njy can you please help with what is the rate limits of this end point ? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/url i did not find any doc regarding its limits.

Comment: @PareshBalar see here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Comment: @njy: this url `graph.facebook.com/?fields=share&id=http://www.google.com` does not require any token. it seems open url. how limits will be applied and counted for this ?

Comment: @PareshBalar again, here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting . While testing locally on my dev machine it worked very well, but on prod servers I kept receiving a "rate limit" error.

Comment: If it helps - the ones that I have tested and are working are available wrapped up in some PHP and JS here: https://github.com/lucep/LucepSiteChecker

Answer (score 200):

**UPDATE - April '15:**

If you want to get the count that is available in the Like button, you should use the `engagement` field in the `og_object` object, like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?id=http://www.MY-LINK.com&fields=og_object{engagement}&access_token=<access_token>
```

Result:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "engagement": {
      "count": 93, 
      "social_sentence": "93 people like this."
    }, 
    "id": "801998203216179"
  }, 
  "id": "http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/06/they-should-have-announced-at-420/"
}
```

---

It's possible with the Graph API, simply use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_URL
```

something like:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com
```

Would return:

```
{
   "id": "http://www.google.com",
   "shares": 1163912
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** while the above would answer how to get the *share* count. This number is **not** equal to the one you see on the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), since that number is the sum of:

- The number of likes of this URL
- The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
- The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

So getting the Like Button number is possible with the Graph API through the [`fql`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) end-point (the [`link_stat`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) table):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.google.com'
```

`total_count` is the number that shows in the Like Button.

Comment: I don't get the share count for certain objects. I know they should have at least one share.

Comment: @Fair, yes sometimes the number is not correct and it's a bit confusing. You may use the fql table suggested by the other answer, but still...sometimes numbers there is not correct too!

Comment: is it possible to take shares of few sites?

Comment: i use this all the time

Comment: is there a call limit per hour?

Comment: oops: Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"message":"(#4) Application request limit reached","type":"OAuthException","code":4}}

Comment: @ifaour Where is the `engagement` field documented?

Comment: @Tobi: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url) you go :)

Comment: As [v2.6 doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/url) does not let you get `share_count`, `like_count` and `comment_count`, it seems `fql` and the REST API are still the best options ... **But both `fql` and REST API will no longer be available after 7th August 2016!** Any suggestions?

Comment: Did this change recently? Now I have to use access token to get the value and it looks like: {
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 977027
   },
   "id": "http://www.apple.com"
}

Comment: As @edelwater mentioned, I'm too getting the same error. What to do now since both the methods are not working properly now as mentioned by Daniel?

Answer (score 21):

You should not use graph api. If you either call:

- http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.apple.com

or

- http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.apple.com

both will return:

```
{
  "id": "http://www.apple.com",
  "shares": 1146997
}
```

**But the number shown is the sum of**:

- number of likes of this URL
- number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
- number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

So you must use FQL.
Look at this answer:   [How to fetch facebook likes, share, comments count from an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137414/how-to-fetch-facebook-likes-share-comments-count-from-an-article/7707702#7707702)

Comment: you are absolutely right, by total_shares is sum of comments+likes+shares
but the page i requested, shows shares_i_have = total_shares + likes

Answer (score 14):

After August 7, 2016 you can still make your call like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.apple.com/
```

but the response format is going to be different: it won't be

```
{
  "id": "http://www.apple.com",
  "shares": 1146997
}
```

but instead it will be

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "388265801869",
      "description": "Get a first look at iPhone 7, Apple Watch Series 2, and the new AirPods \u2014 the future of wireless headphones. Visit the site to learn more.",
      "title": "Apple",
      "type": "website",
      "updated_time": "2016-09-20T08:21:03+0000"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 1,
      "share_count": 1094227
   },
   "id": "https://www.apple.com"
}
```

So you will have to process the response like this:

```
reponse_variable.share.share_count
```

Comment: But the share_count value is misleading, as it's referring to the sum of likes+shares

Comment: I guess you're right, my answer was just an update on how to call the API. I think what @freedev said about share counts may still be correct.

Answer (score 8):

What I found useful and I found on one link above is this FQL query where you ask for likes, total, share and click count of one link by looking at the link_stat table

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count,%20comment_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20=%20%22http://google.com%22
```

That will output something like this:

```
{
    data: [
        {
             like_count: 3440162,
             total_count: 13226503,
             share_count: 7732740,
             click_count: 265614,
             comment_count: 2053601
         }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As of August 8, 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried. To migrate your app, use the API Upgrade Tool to see the Graph API calls you can make instead.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302). It has snippets for how to get the sharing count for the following services:

- Facebook
- Twitter
- Google plus
- Pinterest
- LinkedIn
- StumbledUpon

Comment: This is a few years old. With how often each service updates their API, I doubt it's very accurate.

Answer (score 4):

The facebook like button does two things that the API does not do. This might create confusion when you compare the two.

1. If the URL you use in your like button has a redirect the button will actually show the count of the redirect URL versus the count of the URL you are using.
2. If the page has a og:url property the like button will show the likes of that url instead of the url in the browser.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 3):

Simply type in `https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=share&id=https://www.example.com` and replace example with your url or page you are looking for.

Example of Google:
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=share&id=https://www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

when i used FQL I found the problem (but it is still problem)
the documentation says that the number shown is the sum of:

- number of likes of this URL
- number of shares of this URL (this
  includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- number of likes and
  comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
- number of inbox
  messages containing this URL as an attachment.

but on my website the shown number is sum of these 4 counts + number of shares (again)

Answer (score 1):

Using FQL you could do that:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='PASTE_YOUR_URL_HERE'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a ruby gem for it - [SocialShares](https://github.com/Timrael/social_shares)

Currently it supports following social networks:

- facebook
- twitter
- google plus
- reddit
- linkedin
- pinterest
- stumbleupon
- vkontakte
- mail.ru
- odnoklassniki

Usage:

```
:000 > url = 'http://www.apple.com/'
  => "http://www.apple.com/"
:000 > SocialShares.facebook url
  => 394927
:000 > SocialShares.google url
  => 28289
:000 > SocialShares.twitter url
  => 1164675
:000 > SocialShares.all url
  => {:vkontakte=>44, :facebook=>399027, :google=>28346, :twitter=>1836, :mail_ru=>37, :odnoklassniki=>1, :reddit=>2361, :linkedin=>nil, :pinterest=>21011, :stumbleupon=>43035}
:000 > SocialShares.selected url, %w(facebook google linkedin)
  => {:facebook=>394927, :google=>28289, :linkedin=>nil}
:000 > SocialShares.total url, %w(facebook google)
  => 423216
:000 > SocialShares.has_any? url, %w(twitter linkedin)
  => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{Place_your_Page_ID here}/feed?fields=id,shares,share_count&access_token={Place_your_access_token_here} to get the shares count.