# How to fetch facebook likes, share, comments count from an article

Tags: php, facebook

I need to fetch facebook likes,share, comments count from an article

Is there any way to **fetch facebook (likes,share, comments) count**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: atleast do a little bit research...

Comment: @Gokhan: asking someone to do it for you does not count as research? I'll make a note of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get share counts using graph api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually you can have a more detailed report using FQL. 
Try following query:

- SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'www.apple.com'

Here the php code:

```
$fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
$fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
$fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = 'www.apple.com'";

$apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
$json=file_get_contents($apifql);
print_r( json_decode($json));
```

And this is the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [url] => www.apple.com
            [normalized_url] => http://www.apple.com/
            [share_count] => 355693
            [like_count] => 500374
            [comment_count] => 290890
            [total_count] => 1146957
            [commentsbox_count] => 2
            [comments_fbid] => 388265801869
            [click_count] => 16558
        )

)
```

Comment: any idea how to get a list of the people who shared via FQL? (or any other way ... I think you cannot via the GraphAPI)

Comment: @freedev Does this solution apply to apple.com/viewArticle/245?

Comment: fql is deprecated. USe Graph API. See answer below

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me:

```
<?php
$source_url = "http://www.flightpodcast.com/episode-6-john-bartels-qantas-qf30";
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo "Share --- ".$shares = $xml->link_stat->share_count;
echo "<br/>";

echo "Like --- ".$likes = $xml->link_stat->like_count;
echo "<br/>";

echo "Comments ---".$comments = $xml->link_stat->comment_count; 
echo "<br/>";

echo "Total --- ".$total = $xml->link_stat->total_count;
echo "<br/>";

echo $max = max($shares,$likes,$comments);
```

Comment: This works great! I'm noticing something which has nothing to do with your code but with facebook: I am using the facebook comments plugin on a WordPress site. Facebook isn't counting the comments as actual "comments", but as "shares". Furthermore, deleting a comment from the facebook 'module' on the WP site, or from my facebook profile doesn't reduce the "shares" count... Going to also make a separate question on this one.

Comment: Thanks a million. Your are using the "old" REST API. facebook writes on ther documentation site, that this is deprecated. Do you or somebody else know how to get these counters using the "new" Graph API?

Comment: I think you can now only get likes with the Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $photoid = $row['photoid'];
    $likes = $facebook->api("/$photoid/likes");


    echo "<br><br>".$row['photoid'];
    echo "<br />";

    foreach ($likes['data'] as $like)
    {
        $likeid = $like['id'];
        $name =  $like['name'];
        echo "<br>like : ".$like['id']."  , ".$like['name'];

        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO photo_like VALUES (%s,%s,'%s')",$user_id,$likeid,$name);

        echo "<br>query string : ".$query."<br><br>";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
                            $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                            $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
                            echo "<br>";
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Graph API  as FQL is deprecated, The 101.. you see in the url is the article id

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

[image]

Comment: add limit(0) to have only the summary