# The graph of Facebook doesn't work anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having an issue when I'm trying to get total shares and comments.

Output:

```
{
   "http://website/post/the-christmas-is-coming": {
      "url": "http://website/post/the-christmas-is-coming",
      "type": "website",
      "title": "website",
      "image": [
         {
            "url": "http://website/ads/300x250.png"
         }
      ],
      "description": "website",
      "updated_time": "2012-12-07T12:24:14+0000",
      "id": "131852063636099"
   }
}
```

Where's the problem ?

LE: **How to fix it ?**

[How to fetch facebook likes, share, comments count from an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137414/how-to-fetch-facebook-likes-share-comments-count-from-an-article)

Comment: Whats the problem here? Whats your issue?

Comment: @Tommy Crush, the graph should return the shares and comments and the output is that... last week worked perfectly

Comment: Gonna need to url to debug this one.

Answer (score -1):

for this probleme, use this graph call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27
```