# How to track public URLs on Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, public

Is there any way to track a certain URL (let's say `http://domain.com/example`) on Facebook and Twitter? Do any of the respective APIs enable users to access the number of public shares, likes or retweets from a given public publication/tweet, without forcing users to authenticate?

Comment: There is a similar question (with answers about different social networks, including Twitter) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api 
And a usefull Gist here: https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Facebook you can do it by usin Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
```

To retrieve comments, you should use **comments** connection:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
```

And so on.