# Getting google plus shares for a given URL in PHP

Tags: php, google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to get the number of shares on google plus for a given URL in PHP. I found this function to do that:

```
function get_shares_google_plus($url) {
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
  $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
  curl_close ($curl);
  $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
  print_r($json);
  return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
}
```

However, I always get the same message: `Notice: Undefined index: result in ...`.

I make `print_r($json)`, and I get: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [code] => 400 [message] => Invalid Value [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [domain] => global [reason] => invalid [message] => Invalid Value ) ) ) [id] => p )`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The RPC API was never meant for public use and Google changed authentication in order to prevent abuse. Thus, the code that you posted does not work any longer. However, I found a much simpler solution:

**Update (23.01.2013):** Google blocked this URL in december 2012 - so this method doesn't work any longer!
**Update (15.05.2013):** The method works again!

```
<?php
/**
 * Get the numeric, total count of +1s from Google+ users for a given URL.
 * @author          Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 * @copyright       Copyright (c) 2013 Stephan Schmitz
 * @license         http://eyecatchup.mit-license.org/  MIT License
 * @link            <a href="https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/8495140">Source</a>.
 * @param   $url    string  The URL to check the +1 count for.
 * @return  intval          The total count of +1s.
 */
function getGplusShares($url) {
    $url = sprintf('https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=%s', urlencode($url));
    preg_match_all('/{c: (.*?),/', file_get_contents($url), $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    return (1 === sizeof($match) && 2 === sizeof($match[0])) ? intval($match[0][1]) : 0;
}
```

---

**Update (18.01.2014):** Here's an improved version that uses curl, a fallback host and does some error handling (the latest version can be found here https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/8495140).

```
<?php
/**
 * GetPlusOnesByURL()
 *
 * Get the numeric, total count of +1s from Google+ users for a given URL.
 *
 * Example usage:
 * <code>
 *   $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/';
 *   printf("The URL '%s' received %s +1s from Google+ users.", $url, GetPlusOnesByURL($url));
 * </code>
 *
 * @author          Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 * @copyright       Copyright (c) 2014 Stephan Schmitz
 * @license         http://eyecatchup.mit-license.org/  MIT License
 * @link            <a href="https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/8495140">Source</a>.
 * @link            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385591/624466">Read more</a>.
 *
 * @param   $url    string  The URL to check the +1 count for.
 * @return  intval          The total count of +1s.
 */
function GetPlusOnesByURL($url) {
    !$url && die('No URL, no results. ;)');

    !filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) &&
        die(sprintf('PHP said, "%s" is not a valid URL.', $url));

    foreach (array('apis', 'plusone') as $host) {
        $ch = curl_init(sprintf('https://%s.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=%s',
                                      $host, urlencode($url)));
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) ' .
                                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' .
                                      'Chrome/32.0.1700.72 Safari/537.36' ));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $curlinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (200 === $curlinfo['http_code'] && 0 < strlen($response)) { break 1; }
        $response = 0;
    }
    !$response && die("Requests to Google's server fail..?!");

    preg_match_all('/window\.__SSR\s\=\s\{c:\s(\d+?)\./', $response, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    return (1 === sizeof($match) && 2 === sizeof($match[0])) ? intval($match[0][1]) : 0;
}
```

---

**Update (02.11.2017):** The +1 count is officially dead! As announced in [this Google+ Post](https://plus.google.com/110610523830483756510/posts/Z1FfzduveUo) by Product Manager John Nack Google recently removed the share count (aka +1 Count) from their web Sharing buttons. *(They claim that the purpose of this move is for making the +1 button and share box load more quickly.)*

Comment: Hm, seems like they blocked it. However, if you use HTTPS it still works (updated answer).

Comment: Nice workaround! It can also break if Google change stuff, but until it does...(really don't understand why google doesn't give easy access to this like fb and twitter)

Comment: Yep, I don't understand it neither. Especially when you look at the fact that Google defined this tag <meta name="interactionCount" content="UserPlusOnes:NUMBER_THAT_I_CANT_GET" > for schema.org. So tell me Google, how will we write this tag if we can’t request the count?

Comment: @PepeLópez: Yes, it was blocked back in december already. However, there is another way to get the count. ;-)

Comment: Any updates in Feb 2014 for this? I get 0 for any URL. What a pain huh!

Comment: @BenRacicot Check your error messages. The code still works for me - as is: http://i.imgur.com/xrjFeX9.jpg

Comment: Any updates on this one. Really need it. Noticed that not even in the developers console there is no possibility of getting this.

Comment: @Adrian As announced in [this Google+ Post](https://plus.google.com/110610523830483756510/posts/Z1FfzduveUo) by Product Manager John Nack Google recently removed the share count (aka +1 Count) from their web Sharing buttons. _(They claim that the purpose of this move is for making the +1 button and share box load more quickly.)_

Answer (score 1):

This code is not going to work. Additionally, there's no publicly available API that provides this count.

This code uses the RPC API that powers the +1 button. This API is not an officially supported API, and is not intended to be used outside of the internal implementation of [Google+ plugins](http://developers.google.com/+/plugins).

Answer (score 0):

**The cURL and API way listed in the other posts here no longer works.**

[There is still at least 1 method](http://shinraholdings.com/870/count-facebook-likes-twitter-links-and-google-pluses-with-php/#google-plus), but it's ugly and Google clearly doesn't support it. You just rip the variable out of the JavaScript source code for the official button with a regular expression:

```
function shinra_gplus_get_count( $url ) {
    $contents = file_get_contents( 
        'https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=' 
        . urlencode( $url ) 
    );

    preg_match( '/window\.__SSR = {c: ([\d]+)/', $contents, $matches );

    if( isset( $matches[0] ) ) 
        return (int) str_replace( 'window.__SSR = {c: ', '', $matches[0] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the code that I posted a couple of months ago. Why creating duplicated answers?