# Count facebook shares in real time

Tags: facebook, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get share counts using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api)

I've got a site where I sell stuff online. 
I'd like to add an FB share button below an item, so that every time that button is clicked and that link is shared (whether through my website or on Facebook itself), the item price is decreased by an X amount.

So my question is: Is it possible to track or count the amount of times a link has been shared overall?

Thanks

Comment: It's not exactly an answer, but I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/intro-action-specs/) on the facebook developer page. Essentially, you can query the open graph to find and count all the shares your object has received with an HTTP request.  You could set up a jQuery timer to automatically ping for updated share counts every so often, then run the calculation for item price based on the total count.

Comment: Thanks for that! I had a read and it seems they track shares/comments/likes on a fan pages or posts of others. How about counting number of shares for a UNIQUE URL? e.g. how many times a particular link has been shared on FB?