# I want remove the facebook button only

Tags: javascript, css

I  want remove facebook like button in my website (but count should be display ). Can anybody help me out of this .? or is it possible to change the like button Design ?

Comment: Can you paste a piece of code surrounding that HTML-tag in you question? You can probably remove the button afterwards with jQuery by adjusting the CSS or DOM dynamically.

Comment: You can't just hide the 'like' part of the like box. It's in an iframe and there is no option to only display the like number.

Comment: Hi Allendar , Code given below :<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fredxinds&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;
width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">
 </iframe>

Comment: Ok since Iframe could use filgetcontents to remake it

Answer (score 2):

You could not do much with css/javascript as the whole button in `iframe` and has different url than your page, and according the browser security you do not access into it. But you could use [Graph API/FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api) to get like counts and than use it on the page the way you need.