# Is an access token needed for facebook fql query on link_stat

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In Facebook's documentation for fql link_stats (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat), under Permissions it says "To read the link_stat table you need - a valid app access_token"

In the browser I can do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='https://medium.com/health-the-future/918b3d08f21f'
```

which I got from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api). As you can see there is no access token in the call.

This api call is the same as the one in the linked documentation correct? So do you or do you not need an access token to query fql via this graph api call? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require any access token to access the link stats table now.(There can be restrictions later)

Regarding the app access tokens,they are largely used when posting requests to the API.

In the developer documentation,they have mentioned it to be used for certain retrieval options too.
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right. Surprisingly, you don't require any Access Token to the **link_stat** table. I've tried it with URL and as well as using the Graph Explorer (after clearing the Access Token of course) and it's working just fine.

To sum up: No, you don't require an Access Token for that.

PS: You can report this thing to Facebook, if you want.