# Filter an RSS feed to show only more popular links

Tags: filter, rss, pipe, yahoo, popularity

I have an RSS feed that outputs around 100 articles per day. I wish to filter it to include only the more popular links, perhaps filter it to 50 or less. Back in the day, I believe you could use "postrank" to do this, but is now defunct after Google acquisition.

Anyone know how I can filter a specific RSS feed to include only the more popular outputs?

Thank you!

Comment: Define "popular"? What criteria do you want to use?

Comment: Whatever... I'd probably play around with the criteria and make it looser or stricter to just get the 100 per day articles down to like 30 or so articles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite open, but one way to measure "popularity" of a post would be to **use social networks**.

Each post is probably associated with a certain URL, which can referred to on social networks. On facebook, for instance, one can share or like it. You could now get the number of shares for each post, order your list based on them and pop the top 50 ones.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api) asks for such share stats and contains answers for several networks.

*Caution:* Be aware that you'd need to do at least one API call per article. On the one hand, this may take some time, on the other hand, you'd have be careful to not exceed quotas. You're probably best off by locally caching fetched posts and only refresh every few hours or once a day.