# What's the equivalent of url_like on the Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

One of our apps uses FQL (more specifically the table url_like) as part of the core functionality.

With the upcoming deprecation of FQL we were wondering what is the Graph API endpoint (or set of endpoints) that could provide the same functionality (see likes on friend's links).

So far we haven't been able to. Any clue?

Much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know there's no way yet to do this in a pure Graph API request. To get the `total_shares`, you could use something like

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com
```

but this sums up all likes, shares, comments etc. so it's probably not what you're looking for.

You could use

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.google.com&format=json
```

but this is also deprecated, and it's unclear how long this will work.

**FQL** by the way will be around for another 2 years ***after*** the next version of the Graph API will be released, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#versioning So, for now I'd recommend to stick with the FQL solution.

Hava a look at [How to get share counts using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api) to get some more info.