# Are there limits to non-auth Facebook Graph API requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an app with timely, Facebook statistics (just the total count) associated with web content. The content volume is substantial, and statistics should be updated every few minutes for each url. So the Graph API request count, to http://graph.facebook.com/?id= is massive. Are there limits to the number of requests? I don't batch them.

Only batch limits for apps seem to be communicated:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: This sounds like something they would put in their official documentation.

Comment: there are plenty of threads about facebooks api limits already, please use the search function on stackoverflow or google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api#comment47158910_19119580 is all I could find here.

Comment: There’s different types of limits, and Facebook doesn’t disclose what all of them are; some of them are even dynamic. Doing a “substantial” data grab, and that every few minutes as well, is likely to run into limits quite easily. Apart from requesting data for multiple ids at once and/or using batch requests, you should consider using user access tokens (if at all possible) – the larger your user base, the less easy you run into any limits then.

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely add an App Access Token, and you should definitely use

```
/?ids={url1},{url2},{url3},...
```

to reduce your requests. There are no published actual request limits of the Graph API.