# Get share count from Graph API efficiently

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get information about a set of user posts (last 20 posts). For each post, I would like to simply get likes, comments and shares count.

So far I was able to get the like and comment count, but I had no luck in retrieving the share count.

This is the query I used:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=x&limit=20&fields=id,comments.limit(0).summary(true),likes.limit(0).summary(true)`

I understand that there are ways to retrieve the share count using the object id, but I would like to refrain from making 20 different requests in order to obtain this field.

Is there any other way that I can make a single batch request to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get share count through `engagement` field of the object, as mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700882/533399

For batching your requests, graph api already supports batch requests :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: I appreciate this, but your answer does not provide an explanation on how to link both actions. Also, the first link uses an URL as an example, while I may only have the ID of a private post, for instance. Is it possible to get the share count on that?