# Facebook Graph API | Marketing Insights - Count Shares and Likes, Haha, Love...Etc for an AD

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

Is it possible to get Share Count as well the actions count for likes, ahah, dislike etc via the Facebook API / Marketing insights?

So far I'm able to get this data for posts(which are related to ads if promoted), but this is a lifetime metric I can't have the numbers in a daily basis, unless I calculate it by doing the difference once I have the data.
Also, I would never now, if the likes are being made by someone who saw my post somewhere because its promoted, or if that person went directly to my page.

Is there any way to achieve this results?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon that question has nothing to do with mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `actions` field in insights, you should see a field called `post_reaction` which is the total number of reactions for your ad in the requested timeframe.

To get a daily breakdown, use `time_increment=1` and `time_range` to specify the date range.

I don't believe we provide breakdowns on the different reaction types however.

Docs for parameters:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v2.9