# How To Track Number of Times Post Was Shared - Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

The task I want to accomplish is simple: track the number of times a post on my blog has been shared because I want the number to be displayed beside the post. However, I cannot figure it out.

Here is the the anchors with hrefs that allow the user to click on them and share the post on social media:

```
<ul class="mb-30 list-a-bg-grey list-a-hw-radial-35 list-a-hvr-primary list-li-ml-5">
    <li class="mr-10 ml-0">Share</li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a Post model with a variable called share_count. Obviously, I have a view that helps renders out the HTML too. My issue is that I do not understand how to connect the hrefs to my view in order to increment the share_count of the post in the database.

I searched all over and could not find an answer, I would appreciate any help or hints.

Also, can you explain it as if you are telling someone who just started web development...oh wait, that is exactly what is going on!

Comment: You can query the APIs of Facebook/Twitter to obtain the share count: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119580/67579

Comment: Alternatively, you can intercept the click event in javascript (make sure your `preventDefault()`), send an ajax request to a view that collects the shares, and finally in javascript set the window location to the url of the button (twitter or facebook) so the user loads the share page.

Comment: What if all I want to do is increment a counter in my database everytime one of the anchors is clicked? How would I do that? @WillemVanOnsem